# Antizer form submit data handling

Tags: clojurescript, reagent-forms

I would like to use ant design components in reagent through antizer but I can't figure out how to extract fields values from the form after submitting. I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://priornix.github.io/antizer/latest/#_return_values).

Someone more expert than me has resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply a callback to the `ant/validate-fields` function, it will receive two arguments: `errors` and `values`.

If the input is valid, `errors` will be `null`.

The second argument will always contain the current form data.

```
;; Receive the output of `ant/validate-fields`, and react accordingly
(defn submit-form-if-valid
  [errors values]
  (if (nil? errors)
    (println "Form is valid."     values)
    (println "Validation failed." errors)))

(defn sample-form
  (fn [props]
    (let [my-form         (ant/create-form)
          submit-handler #(ant/validate-fields my-form submit-form-if-valid)]
      [:div
       [ant/form {:on-submit #(do
                                (.preventDefault %)
                                (submit-handler))}
         [ant/form-item ...]
         [ant/form-item ...]
         [ant/form-item ...]
         [ant/form-item
           [ant/button {:type "primary"
                        :html-type "submit"}
            "Submit"]]]])))
```

**Note:** Personally, I only use this function to check for `errors`. My form data is continually recorded in the [app-db](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Subscribing-To-A-Database) every time the user changes a field. So my submit handler looks more like this:

```
(defn submit-form-if-valid
  [errors _]
  (when (nil? errors)
    (dispatch [:sample-form/submit!])))
```

My re-frame events look something like this. One event to update the form data in DB (using the key/value pair provided by a form input), and another to actually submit the form:

```
(reg-event-db
 :sample-form/update-value
 [(path db/path)]
 (fn [db [_ k v]]
   (assoc-in db [:sample-form-data k] v)))

(reg-event-fx
 :sample-form/submit!
 [(path db/path)]
 (fn [{:keys [db]} _]
   (let [form-data (:sample-form-data db)])
     ;; ... send data to back-end, handle the response, etc.
  ))
```

And each of my form inputs invoke that event like this:

```
[ant/form-item 
  (ant/decorate-field my-form "Thing #1" {:rules [{:required true}]}
    [ant/input {:on-change #(dispatch [:sample-form/update-value :thing1 (-> % .-target .-value)])}])]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't understood that I could simply use function calls in :on-change event directly from every field.  Thank's a lot for the suggested implementation, it definetely helps a lot!